# Does sprite-kit make images larger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a sprite kit game and I can't figure out why it won't scale my image the way I want it to. The game is in the landscape orientation. This is the code I'm having a problem with:

```
SKSpriteNode *Pathway = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"path.png"] size:CGSizeMake(568, 220)];
Pathway.zPosition = -1.0;
Pathway.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
Pathway.name = @"Pathway";

[self addChild:Pathway];
```

Basically I want the texture to be like this on the screen: [image]

But for some reason, even when I change the size of the texture (568, 220), it scales the image and doesn't fit on the screen.

I tried using `[Pathway setScale:0.7];` which was close to the size I was looking for, but I need to to be exactly 568 x 220. **How come it keeps distorting my image even when I'm setting its size of 568 x 220?**

If more info is needed please let me know, I think this should suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are testing this on device with Retina display.

Rename path.png to path@2x.png and use `[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"path"]` instead of `[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"path.png"]`. This should solve you problem.

Read Apple's tutorial [Supporting High-Resolution Screens In Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html) for more info.

Comment: so you're saying we don't need to manually input each retina image and test if the device is retina or no?

Comment: No, of course you don't have to do that manually. Include both `path.png` and `path@2x.png` to the project and let iOS to choose which one to use automatically.

Comment: I'm only testing it on the 4-inch simulator though. This was useful info for when I do test it on a retina device however. @AndreyGordeev

Comment: @LiamStockhomme It doesn't matter, actually. 4-inch simulator has simulated Retina display

Comment: True. I tried it out and it was a little bit closer to what I wanted. But for some reason now the image is too small. Do you think it's the image size maybe? @AndreyGordeev

Comment: Don't use `xScale`, `yScale`. Try to make image bigger

Answer (score 0):

Using setScale directly scales content proportional and thus resulting in the sprite that follows same aspect ratio as it is before scaling.

Try setting xScale and yScale properties to scale irrespective of aspect ratio